# Usar modal para exibir uma UITableView estática

Tags: objective-c, tabela-html, storyboard

Ola! 
 Estou tentado mostrar uma UITableView estática usando transição modal. Mas quando clico no botão não mostra nada. Fiz um teste para outra view e funcionou corretamente. Mas quando é realizado com a view que contem a tabela estática não ocorre nenhum erro mas também não é exibida a tela.

Estou usando o storyboard.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Preciso que quando o botão "Adicionar" na imagem acima seja tocado chame a tela ao lado.

Obrigado!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Já que tudo está sendo pelo `storyboard` não tem segredo chamar o modal da Table estática:

Pra chamar uma view normal como você citou o ciclo provavelmente foi esse:

- **Passo 1**:

  [image: passo1]
- **Passo 2**:

[image: passo2]

- **Passo 3**:

[image: passo3]

---

Pra chamar a view com a Table estática o ciclo é praticamente o mesmo:

- **Passo 1 para table estatica**:

[image: passo1static]

- **Passo 2 para table estatica**:

[image: passo2static]

- **Passo 3 para table estatica**:

[image: passo3static]

Comment: Bom amigo, no meu caso eu tive que 'embed in' a tabela static em um Navigation Controller para fazer a transição :P

Comment: Com navigation fica mais fácil ainda e ainda tem um componente pronto com uma tabela embutida.

Comment: Sim foi muito util e eu tbm precisava do UiNavigationController! Eliminei duas questoes com uma solucao! Mas obrigado, sua atençao e sua dedicação em dar uma resposta detalhada e com imagens merece o meu respeito e de muitos outros! Obrigado novamente!!